# Keeping class this when calling button click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to keep the class `this` when entering a click function from a button?

For example:

```
class MyClass extends FooClass{

  constructor (obj) {

    super (obj)

    this.obj= obj;

    $("#someButton").click(this.foo);
  }

  foo(){
    this.obj; // undefined because this is now #someButton and not MyClass 
  }
```

But I want to access `this.obj` in `foo()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind `foo`

```
$("#someButton").click(this.foo.bind(this));
```

or use arrow function

```
$("#someButton").click(() => this.foo());
```

Comment: That did it. Is there a difference between the two approaches? The second one is just calling the function? Why wouldn't `() => this.foo` work then?

Comment: `bind` creates new function with bounded context which is ES5 way to keep context in callbacks. `() => blah` creates new arrow function and was introduced in ES201Somthing. They are different in some aspects but in this case should work "the same" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions 
"Why wouldn't `() => this.foo` work then?" `() => body` creates new arrow function `this.foo` simply accessing `foo` w/o call. So you need `this.foo()`

Answer (score -1):

Why are you not defining a parameter for the function foo:

```js
$("#someButton").click(function(){
  foo(obj);
});


foo(obj){
  // work with obj ... 
}
```

Comment: How would he access `foo`?